# Vim: prevent line break within brackets or some environments (latex)

Tags: vim, latex

I currently using the vim-latex plugin and a self-written tex.vim setting.

However I normally using a textwith of 80 by having the setting `:set tw=80`. But i don't want line-breaks within captions like

`\caption{looongwritten text...
foo }`

or in eqnarrays environments like:

`\begin{eqnarray}
LOONG formulars
unwanrted wrap
\end{eqnarray}`

Is there a way to prevent the automatic line wrap inside `{}` and some defined environments like `eqnarray`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code for equations

```
%s/\\begin{eqnarray}\s*\n*\(\zs[^\(\n\)]*\ze\n\)\\end{eqnarray}/\=substitute(submatch(1),'\n', '', 'g')/gec
```

and this for captions, but ensure that, the caption should not contains sub braces like \textit,\textbf{}  etc... inside it

```
%s/\\caption{\(\zs\_[^}]*\ze\)}/\=substitute(submatch(1),'\n', ' ', 'g')/gec
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, it's unrelated. The question was how to prevent the linewrap (done by tw=80) in vim, not manually remove already typed ones by doing some regexp's